# Circle dimensions set with rem and vmin squished at small sizes

Tags: html, css

## Problem

I am trying to set my root `font-size` to use `vmin` and `px` in a `calc()` function. When setting a circle div's `height` and `width` with `rem`, said circle is "squished" at small sizes (see photo and link below). When the div is inspected, the computed width and height are reported to be equal, despite its "squished" appearance.

[Link to JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drm1217/u7n1scde/22/)

[image: Image of squished circle at small size bug]

```css
html {
  font-size: calc(10vmin + 1px);
}

.circle {
  height: 1rem;
  width: 1rem;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</html>
```

## Troubleshooting

When the `height` and `width` are changed to a `px` value the issue is fixed. Additionally changing the root font-size to not use `vmin`, `vh` or `vw` to calculate the size also seems to fix the problem.

As pointed out by [Aditya Sarin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13187126/aditya-sarin), changing the size of the div using `vh` or `vw` also fixes the error. It seems the only way to reproduce this error is by using `calc()` with a viewport unit and `px` value.

## Question

Why does using `calc()` with a viewport unit seem to cause this error? Is it generally not considered wise to mix a viewport unit with a `px` value to create responsive `rem` sizes?

Comment: Your code looks fine. My first thought was that it was something like the default padding on a div interfering. But  I can't reproduce the squishing by shrinking the window size on a Windows10 system using Chrome, Edge or Firefox. What browser/OS/device are you using?

Comment: @AHaworth I'm using a PC running Windows 10 and running this using Chrome 88, Firefox 85 and Chromium Edge. This a toy example of a web application that requires small circular icons in flexboxes. The issue was reproduced on all browsers.

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm not seeing the problem - what size do you go down to to see it?

Comment: I don't see the problem...

Comment: @AHaworth in the JSFiddle when the viewport width is 100px.

Comment: Thanks, I've now seen it. I tried radial-gradient background-image instead - it was worse, sort of spikey. Also tried +2px with some thought that an odd number of pixels (11px rem) would be more difficult for the system as it would be centering on a half CSS pixel which may be 1 screen pixel, or even something like 1.5. However, didn't do much. I suspect that down at the around 10px level you can't get a really good looking circle. Just not enough pixels to fill out the curve, even if the system's maths was perfect and it wasn't trying to juggle screen versus CSS pixels.

Comment: @AHaworth, what's so weird about this example is that, at least for me, the problem is fixed when I switch to `px` or viewport units for the circle size. I can't find similar documented bugs with using `rem` for circles at small sizes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this is an illusion, but having tried both the border-radius method given in the question and background-image radial-gradient (which gave worse results) I think using the filled circle Unicode character gives better results.

Whether the typeface chosen will alter things needs experimentation, as does whether anti aliasing settings make a difference. Here is a snippet with the border-radius and character methods so they can be compared. It is possible that a character will give a better result as typeface designers will understand how to smooth things as far as is possible. It may also be worth trying the larger Unicode filled circle and shrinking it.

```css
html {
  font-size: calc(10vmin + 1px);
}

.circle {
  height: 1rem;
  width: 1rem;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div style="color:blue; font-size: 2.4rem;">&#9679;</div>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems to have fixed the problem, but I still don't understand why using `rem` would do that to a div. Interesting how the problem doesn't affect type though.

Comment: I don't think it is to do with using rem, it seems more to be that the calculations for border whatever dimensions you use, when it's an arc/circle somehow use 'whole' CSS pixels and don't seem to account for being able to use better quality screens - but typefaces are designed for it. (My speculation anyway!).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to specify the dimensions using `vh` and `vw`

Comment: While that does seem to fix the issue, it does not answer the question. However, I've added your observation to the Troubleshooting section. Thanks for pointing that out!